# Build delayed on Azure DevOps too many hours

Tags: build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I commit to master branch yesterday but build process runs today (after 14 hours)

- I'm using Azure DevOps Hosted Agent
- Any issue detected on https://status.dev.azure.com/ for Ubuntu/Windows machines
- My build triggers doesn't have any schedulle

Do you have any suggestions for the reason of the delay? Am I ignoring something relevant?

Screenshot of my **commit**:

[image]

Screenshot of **build**:

[image]

Comment: Could it be because the agent was busy with something else all this time? If this is the only agent your build can run on, it might be the case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @YanSklyarenko. No other work was launched previously that locks this execution (I checked it on agent queue)

Comment: Did it just happen this once or is it still happening?

Comment: @JaneMa-MSFT Apparently it has only happened once